# jQuery not detect field's IDs that gathered by 'path' (jstl)

Tags: java, jquery, jstl, datatables

I am using spring mvc 4 with dandelion datatablse stl.
I am trying to refer to check if dropdown field changed (user select other choice) with jquery using the gathered id.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#task.identifierType1').on("change", function(){
        alert("1");
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form:label path="task.identifierValue">* Identifier ID:</form:label>
                <spring:message code="msg.task.new.identifierValue" var="title"/>
                <form:input type="input" class="form-control input-sm" path="task.identifierValue" placeholder="Enter Identifier ID" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="${title}"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="task.identifierValue" cssClass="validationError"/>
</div>
```

From inspect elements in firefox: `<select data-original-title="OPs that under the selected identifier will be checked" id="task.identifierType" name="task.identifierType" title="" data-placement="left" class="form-control input-sm"`.

No alert.
I don't understand why I can't refer to `task.identifierValue` via jQuery.
(I have the same issue with other fields as well).

Note that when adding a class to the requested `select` field it's work fine.
The problem is only with attributes that gathered via `path`.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: you need to escape the `.` like `'#task\\.identifierType1'`

Comment: Works!! I tried many variations but not with double escape (only single). thanks!

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/